# Custom sorting of a query

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

The application I am working on displays some tasks based on status, and date (in that order). However, for a particular status, the sort condition should be inverted. For example, a table which looks like this :

```
 id    | status   | planned_date
-------+----------+--------------
 1     | inactive | 2015-03-12
 2     | active   | 2015-03-13
 3     | inactive | 2015-03-13
 4     | inactive | 2015-03-14
 5     | active   | 2015-03-12
 6     | active   | 2015-03-16
 7     | active   | 2015-03-17
```

Should be returned as

```
 id    | status   | planned_date
-------+----------+--------------
 5     | active   | 2015-03-12
 2     | active   | 2015-03-13
 6     | active   | 2015-03-16
 7     | active   | 2015-03-17
 4     | inactive | 2015-03-14
 3     | inactive | 2015-03-13
 1     | inactive | 2015-03-12
```

**Note**: For this example to be simple, only two statuses are used, but this is an `enum`eration of 6 different values for this field; `new`, `pending`, `active`, `inactive`, `cancelled`, `completed`. Also, there are other fields that need to be sorted: `planned_date`, and `priority` (a numeric value from `-3` to `3`, `0` being "normal"). I am mentioning this only as a FYI, as I don't believe it to be much relevant, and that the general idea can be understood with the simple example above.

To sort by the `status` field (an `enum`) I simply perform

```
SELECT id, status, planned_date
FROM tbl_tasks
WHERE ...
ORDER BY status ASC;
```

Now, how do I sort the `planned_date` field (`ASC` for `active` status, and `DESC` for `inactive` status)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `CASE WHEN` operator for solving this:

```
ORDER BY status,
    CASE status
        WHEN 'active' THEN planned_date - now()
        WHEN 'inactive' THEN now() - planned_date
    END
```

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
select *
from t
order by status,
         case status 
             when 'active'   then  1 
             when 'inactive' then -1
         end 
         * row_number() over (partition by status order by planned_date) ;
```

Test at [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d865c/4)

Comment: Wow... :) Is this faster than the Simo's answer?

Answer (score 2):

Accidentally read this as a SQL Server question, for Postgres it would have to be a [materialized view](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/rules-materializedviews.html) to do the equivalent. I'll re-use Simo's logic for the sake of consistency.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW view AS
  SELECT
      id, status,
      CASE status_date
         WHEN 'active' THEN planned_date - now()
         WHEN 'inactive' THEN now() - planned_date
      END
    FROM table
    WHERE ...
    ORDER BY status, status_date
```

Comment: Can this be used on a view as well?

Comment: Thought this was for SQL Server, so I've updated it as a view that will work for Postgres.